Need an advise on deployment of the queues and workers on an ec2 instance
I am relatively new to programming, I am building a platform for solving DSA questions (like leetcode). I am confused about how to deploy this application since it uses queues and workers to compile and run the code.
Should I deploy the queues and workers separately on another ec2 instance, or should I integrate it in my primary backend, and use a load balancer with multiple ec2 instances running the primary backend?
I tried to integrate the queues in my primary backend but I need an advice from an experienced person.

It's a bit unclear what you're asking.  When you say Queues, do you mean SQS?  What kind of workers - threads, docker containers, etc?  What kind of throughput are you looking for?  We need much more information.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
